# extract function name till the bracket when there are no spaces

Tags: regex, perl

i want to extract function name only from a function definition which are like this format only in Perl

```
static int
function_name (...)
```

my code works for above example

```
$source_line =~ /^(.*?)\s/
```

But fails for the below condition when there is no space after function name

```
static int
function_name(...)
```

how do i make it extract words only till "(".

This should work only for those case in which function name is beginning of the sentence like in the above example

Comment: what do you mean to say??

Comment: `$source_line =~ /^([^(]*)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `\b` which is [zero width assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#ANCHORS),

```
$source_line =~ /^(.+?)\b/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this RegEx: `^\w+\s*\(.*?\)`. But RegEx is really not the way to go for parsing this sort of thing. If you're after a function *definition* this would match a function *call* as well as the definition. You could alleviate this problem by requiring `{}` to match as well with `^\w+\s*\(.*?\)\s*\{[\s\S]+?\}`, but then what happens if there are callbacks or functions within your outer level function? This is where things get dicey.

Comment: i have taken of those(like excluding statements ending with ;in the same line).i just need to handle few exceptions cases

Comment: hey ur previous code was working. after you edited it doesn't work